# Element-wise Maximum of Two DataFrames Ignoring NaNs

Tags: python-3.x, math, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes (df1 and df2) that each have the same rows and columns.  I would like to take the maximum of these two dataframes, element-by-element.  In addition, the result of any element-wise maximum with a number and NaN should be the number.  The approach I have implemented so far seems inefficient:

```
def element_max(df1,df2):
    import pandas as pd
    cond = df1 >= df2
    res = pd.DataFrame(index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)
    res[(df1==df1)&(df2==df2)&(cond)]  = df1[(df1==df1)&(df2==df2)&(cond)]
    res[(df1==df1)&(df2==df2)&(~cond)] = df2[(df1==df1)&(df2==df2)&(~cond)]
    res[(df1==df1)&(df2!=df2)&(~cond)] = df1[(df1==df1)&(df2!=df2)]
    res[(df1!=df1)&(df2==df2)&(~cond)] = df2[(df1!=df1)&(df2==df2)]
    return res
```

Any other ideas?  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A more readable way to do this in recent versions of pandas is concat-and-max:

```python
import scipy as sp
import pandas as pd

A = pd.DataFrame([[1., 2., 3.]])
B = pd.DataFrame([[3., sp.nan, 1.]])

pd.concat([A, B]).max(level=0)
# 
#           0    1    2
#      0  3.0  2.0  3.0 
#
```

Answer (score 21):

You can use [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html#pandas.DataFrame.where) to test your df against another df, where the condition is `True`, the values from `df` are returned, when false the values from `df1` are returned. Additionally in the case where `NaN` values are in `df1` then an additional call to `fillna(df)` will use the values from `df` to fill those `NaN` and return the desired df:

```
In [178]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3))
df.iloc[1,2] = np.NaN
print(df)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3))
df1.iloc[0,0] = np.NaN
print(df1)

          0         1         2
0  2.671118  1.412880  1.666041
1 -0.281660  1.187589       NaN
2 -0.067425  0.850808  1.461418
3 -0.447670  0.307405  1.038676
4 -0.130232 -0.171420  1.192321
          0         1         2
0       NaN -0.244273 -1.963712
1 -0.043011 -1.588891  0.784695
2  1.094911  0.894044 -0.320710
3 -1.537153  0.558547 -0.317115
4 -1.713988 -0.736463 -1.030797

In [179]:
df.where(df > df1, df1).fillna(df)

Out[179]:
          0         1         2
0  2.671118  1.412880  1.666041
1 -0.043011  1.187589  0.784695
2  1.094911  0.894044  1.461418
3 -0.447670  0.558547  1.038676
4 -0.130232 -0.171420  1.192321
```